# Hashmap to link albumid with album name?

Tags: java, sorting, nullpointerexception, hashmap, android-cursor

I'm trying to display the album names and album artwork from the songs on my device.
I tried using a comparator to sort the album names, but when i sort the album names the artwork doesn't match the album name.

How can i link the albumid with the matching artwork?

I use picasso to display the album art and.

I get the album art from  MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM_ID;

Then i tried using a hashmap to link albumid with album name.

But im getting this error;

E/Couldn't execute task: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'boolean android.database.Cursor.moveToFirst()' on a null object reference

```
// Creating the map  "Album IDs" -> "Album Names"
    albumIdToAlbumNameMap = new HashMap<>();

    //This is what we'll ask of the albums
    String[] albumColumns = {
            SONG_ALBUMID,
            SONG_ALBUM,
    };

    // Querying the album database
    cursor = resolver.query(musicUri, albumColumns, null, null, null);

    // Iterating through the results and filling the map.
    for (cursor.moveToFirst(); !cursor.isAfterLast(); cursor.moveToNext())
        albumIdToAlbumNameMap.put(cursor.getString(0), cursor.getString(1));

    cursor.close();

    // Map Song IDs to Album IDs
    songIdToAlbumIdMap = new HashMap<>();

    // For each album, we'll query the databases
    for (String albumID : albumIdToAlbumNameMap.keySet()) {

        Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Albums.getContentUri(albumID);

        cursor = resolver.query(uri, new String[] { SONG_ID }, null, null, null);

        // Iterating through the results, populating the map
        for (cursor.moveToFirst(); !cursor.isAfterLast(); cursor.moveToNext()) {

            long currentSongID = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(SONG_ID));

            songIdToAlbumIdMap.put(Long.toString(currentSongID), albumID);
        }
        cursor.close();
    }


final String musicsOnly = MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC + "=1";

    // Actually querying the system
    cursor = resolver.query(musicUri, columns, musicsOnly, null, null);

    if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst())
    {
        // NOTE: I tried to use MediaMetadataRetriever, but it was too slow.
        //       Even with 10 songs, it took like 13 seconds,

        do {
            // Creating a song from the values on the row
            QuerySongs song = new QuerySongs(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(SONG_ID)),
                    cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(SONG_FILEPATH)));

            song.setTitle      (cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(SONG_TITLE)));
            song.setArtist     (cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(SONG_ARTIST)));
            song.setAlbumID    (cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(SONG_ALBUMID)));

            // Using the previously created genre maps
            // to fill the current song genre.
            String currentGenreID   = songIdToGenreIdMap.get(Long.toString(song.getId()));
            String currentGenreName = genreIdToGenreNameMap.get(currentGenreID);
            String currentAlbumID = songIdToAlbumIdMap.get(Long.toString(song.getId()));
            String currentAlbumName = albumIdToAlbumNameMap.get(currentAlbumID);
            song.setGenre(currentGenreName);
            song.setAlbum(currentAlbumName);

            // Adding the song to the global list
            songs.add(song);
        }
        while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    else
    {
        // What do I do if I can't find any songs?

    }
    cursor.close();
```

**Here does the error occur**

```
  // Iterating through the results, populating the map
        for (cursor.moveToFirst(); !cursor.isAfterLast(); cursor.moveToNext()) {

            long currentSongID = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(SONG_ID));

            songIdToAlbumIdMap.put(Long.toString(currentSongID), albumID);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you need to fix your query input to avoid null in cursor.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but could you explain it a bit more detailed please?